# How to include js library from /sites/all/libraries in twig template with attach_library?

Tags: 8, theming

According to https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/libraries/libraries-and-twig.html, you can include a library within twig template to only load it on specific pages using `{{ attach_library('theme/library') }}`. This appears to be for libraries included in mytheme.libraries.yml.

Is there a way to use this to include a library from sites/all/libraries? It seems silly to add a library to my theme folder when it is already available globally.

Comment: You can add globally available libraries from modules and drupal core in the same way. - About the second part of your question, can you give more details what libraries you have in `/sites/all/libraries`, this looks like the folder name the Libraries API module used in D7, which is not ported to D8 yet.

Comment: When the Libraries API module is ready for D8, loading libraries in twig will be supported, see https://www.drupal.org/node/1704734#comment-11908472

Comment: @4k4, I didn't realize libraries wasn't ready for D8 yet, actually. Modules are still instructing to add reqs to that folder -- probably just for future-proofing. Specifically, for this I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/magnific_popup, so I'm just trying to leverage that js without doubling it up into my theme folder.

Comment: Yes, some D8 modules instruct you to download them to `/libraries` by hand. But these libraries can be used only by the module that instructed you to do so, because no one else knows the location of the files.

Comment: So in this case, since I know the location of the files, could I load them from my theme? Or do I need to wait for Libraries API?

Comment: Until then you need a `*.libraries.yml` file for this, of course you can point this to the files in `/libaries`.

Comment: the module has done this already, see http://cgit.drupalcode.org/magnific_popup/tree/magnific_popup.libraries.yml?h=8.x-1.x

Answer (score 1):

There was likely a module that required the files in question to be added to the sites/all/libraries folder.  You could review that module on how it adds those files as libraries.  Check that module for a .libraries.yml file or check to see if the module implements hook_library_info_build().  Once you know the how to reference the library, you should be able to use the same reference in your twig template.

As an example, the Easychart module (https://www.drupal.org/project/easychart) has both a .libraries.yml and implements the hook in it's .module file.  To reference one of those libraries you would use "easychart/easychart.render" or "easychart/lib.highcharts"